# Why my e4 application addons do not get invoked

Tags: java, eclipse, add-on, e4

I have defined my own addons in an eclipse e4 application. I have a package dependency to javax.annotation(1.2.0)

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.IEclipseContext;

public class LoginServiceAddon {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(IEclipseContext context) {
        LoginService service = context.get(LoginService.class);

        if (service == null) {
            service = ContextInjectionFactory.make(LoginServiceImpl.class, context);

            context.set(LoginService.class, service);
        }
    }
}
```

I can set breakpoints in the addon but it is not hit even thought the standard addons are invoked.

What could be the reason for that behavior?

Comment: Have you added the class to the Add-ons list in the Application.e4xmi?

Comment: yes, I did. Without that it would not work I know.

Comment: Is it in the same plugin as the Application.e4xmi? If it is in a different plugin you probably need to export the package containing the addon class.

Comment: yes they are in the same plugin.

Comment: I solved the problem by removing the persisted state of the application model from the workspaces metadata.Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: OK, it is important to run with -clearPersistedState while doing development that changes the Application.e4xmi